# how to find data based on exact timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to grab a data row in BigQuery by timestamp `'2018-12-08 00:00:42.808 America/Los_Angeles'`. This works with `between` clause. For example, `timestamp BETWEEN '....00:00:42.808...' AND '....00:00:42.809...'`.

However, I'm not able to find anything when I just want to do `timestamp = '....00:00:42.808...'`. I'm not sure why this is and I can't seem to find much answer on google for this particular case.

Comment: You should show some sample data, the actual query as a [mcve] and the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp in Google BigQuery is quite exact, so your query probably does not EXACTLY hit the timestamps in your table. You can use TIMESTAMP_TRUNC -function if you want to hit timestamp at millisecond, second or any rounded level. With this function you can have a where clause like this:

```
where TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, millisecond, 'America/Los_Angeles')='2018-12-08 00:00:42.808 America/Los_Angeles'
```

This would give you the result at millisecond level you expect. You can find more information on TIMESTAMP_TRUNC and other BigQuery functions from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators.